# Resize TextField based on content in Flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

How a TextField width can be resized automatically based on content in Flutter?

An example with 3 TextField which autoresize depending on the content :

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution using the IntrinsicWidth class

```
IntrinsicWidth(
  child: TextField(...
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Only place the `TextField` inside an `Expanded` that will be in a `row`.

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
          child: new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                      child: new TextField(
                        onTap: () {//action of TextField
                        },
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'Password'),
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
                    )),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.apps),
                      onPressed: () {//action of iconbutton
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ])),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think it isn't what I want, I have edit my post with an example of what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Set the maxLines property of TextField to null. maxLines: null

```
            TextField(
              controller: new TextEditingController(
                text: comment
              ),
              maxLines: null,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 12.0,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: HexColor('#ecedec'),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide:BorderSide.none,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                ),
              ),
            )
```